# ng-repeat unique values only (combine duplicates)

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat like this:

```
<option ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'priority'" 
    value="{{item.SAC}}.{{item.difficulty}}">
       {{item.SAC}}.{{item.difficulty}} - {{SACItem(item.SAC).description}}    
</option>
```

I want it to combine any duplicates based on both `item.SAC` and `item.difficulty` if both of those are a duplicate of the repeat they should be combined, otherwise they can be seperate.

I tried the unique filter but I couldn't get it to work with 2 variables.

Comment: since this appears to be a list to be used in a select box, why not create a new array specifically for this purpose in the controller, perform the logic to eliminate duplication when building the list, and then use `ng-options`?

Comment: The items variable is used elsewhere where it shouldn't filter out duplicates

Comment: right, that's my point, create a **new** array, fill it with the non-duplicated values from your `items`, and bind this new array to the select.  You can then still bind the original list in other places without issue.  The `<option>` tag doesn't alter the list, so it doesn't need to be bound to `items`, and if `items` changes, you can easily regenerate the select list.....

Comment: @Jordash: try `ng-repeat="item in items track by $index | orderBy:'priority'"`

Comment: You can't do this in the view. Follow @Claies suggestion and create  filtered array in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a filter:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'john', age:45 },
    { name: 'tim', age: 36 },
    { name: 'bob', age: 44 },
    { name: 'john', age: 45 }
  ];
});

app.filter('unique', function() {
  
  var uniqueItems = [];
  function exists(item, parms) {
    return uniqueItems.some((i) => parms.every((p) => i[p] == item[p]));
  } 
  return function(arr, name, age) {
    
    if (arr) {
      uniqueItems.length = 0;
      angular.forEach(arr, function(item) {
        
        if (!exists(item, [name,age])) {
          uniqueItems.push(item);
        }
      });
      return uniqueItems;
    }
    return arr;
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.js"></script>
<div ng-app ="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h1>Original Array</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item.name }} - {{ item.age }}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h1>Unique Array</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | unique:'name':'age'">
      {{item.name }} - {{ item.age }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can also use this filter in the controller instead of the view:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    var items = [...];
    $scope.items = $filter('unique')(items, 'name', 'age');
});
```